# Google Maps iOS street view URL scheme not working?

Tags: ios, google-maps

My app has some code for opening directly to Google Maps. We're attempting to open directly to Street View for a particular coordinate using a URL like so:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?center=47.613371,-122.313167&mapmode=streetview&x-success=myurlscheme://noop&x-source=MyApp
```

I'm seeing an infinite spinner with the Street View never loading.

This URL scheme is documented and has worked for several years, until a recent update.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme

Is this feature of the app busted or did the URL scheme change?

Comment: Have you specified a callback function? Based on the documentation, `Callbacks are often used to return a user to the app that originally opened Google Maps for iOS.` If you're intending to use the native Maps app, you can just call the `comgooglemapsurl://` schema

Comment: @adjuremods all the callback parameters are configured in the URL example above. I also tested without the parameters and used `comgooglemaps://`. Same repro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest release of google maps iOS app. Please check it.
Reference : https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS/issues/6

Comment: Is this a yearly event from Google? This has been working for a year now, but now it doesn't work again...!

Comment: Google released ver 4.30.0 and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug ( or documentation needs updating) as I was able to verify this working with the previous Google Maps iOS build of 4.14(the last update).  Also verified with other iOS apps that use StreetView.

submitted issue but this has not been acknowledged as a bug yet.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=streetview&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's been accepted as a bug according to Google.   I've heard that it will be fixed with next update, but that is not official.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9095&q=apitype%3AIosSDK%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

Google has a new app, I believe we are supposed to use this instead but I've not tried it yet!!  I still have not seen updated documentation on website that confirms this.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-street-view/id904418768?mt=8

https://github.com/googlemaps/OpenInGoogleMaps-iOS/issues/6

Comment: It looks like this app is focusing on not only showing streetview, but with easy access to all registered imagery, and possibility to add images to share on streetview.